# GCP From pubsub message to trigger multiple instance of cloud function

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a situation where I want to publish a message to Pubsub, which triggers multiple instances of the same cloud function.

here is some information:

- In the pub-sub message, I have project ids separated by ","
- in the cloud function, I want to run the same func for each project id in parallel.

I am able to trigger the cloud function, but it executes only one time it runs. how can I do it? i am using the python.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You might need another pubsub function to invoke once for each project ID.  Without seeing your code and understanding what it's supposed to do, it's hard to tell what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: thank you doug, i uploaded the diagram,. i dont have fancy code, all I am trying to prove if this will working. 1st function send the project ids to pubsubs,.... From pubsub I want to run 1 copy of cloud function for each project id.

Comment: from single pubsub message, can we do concurrent cloud function invocations?

Comment: If there are multiple listeners for the topic, all functions will be invoked. However, there is no way to concurrently invoke the same function multiple times. Consider using a function that invokes your desired function programmatically with each project ID. Or you can publish a new message for each project ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing **exactly** what you are trying to do in the function and the APIs you have available for that, it's not really possible know what your options are.  Without knowing, all I can say is that you will need another pubsub function to invoke for each project in the original message.  Just use the pubsub client in your first function to parse the list of projects, then use the pubsub client API to invoke the second function to run once for each project.

Comment: What I did, was instead of sending a single message, I published one msg for one project id., so now it is triggering a function for each id concurrent.